# Typescript: function return type depending on input function returns type

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

I have a function that takes another function in parameters.
I would like to return a generic interface configured by the return type of the function passed in parameters.

```
function doSomething <T>(values: Whatever[], getter: (whatever: Whatever) => T): T[] {
  return values.map(value => getter(value));
}
```

Then I wanted to make the getter function optional and use a default value for this one. The problem happened at that time.

```
function doSomething <T>(values: Whatever[], getter: (whatever: Whatever) => T = val => val): T[] {
  return values.map(value => getter(value));
}
```

So now I'm getting and error saying :

> Error:(18, 47) TS2322: Type '(val: Whatever) => Whatever' is not assignable to type '(whatever: Whatever) => T'.
>     Type 'Whatever' is not assignable to type 'T'.

Do you have any idea why I'm getting that error ?

Thank you in advance,

(The example below in not my real code but this is more clear for describe my problem)

I'm using typescript 2.7.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that return type of default getter function is `Whatever`, but `doSomething` declaration requires that getter must return `T`. `T` is generic type parameter and it could be anything, it's not guaranteed that `Whatever` will be compatible with `T`. TypeScript compiler does not see that when default value is provided, `T` is not necessary and the return type of `doSomething` is `Whatever[]`. But you can express it with these overload declarations for `doSomething`:

```
function doSomething<T>(values: Whatever[], getter: (whatever: Whatever) => T): T[];
function doSomething(values: Whatever[]): Whatever[];
// the implementation must be compatible with both variants
function doSomething<T>(values: Whatever[], getter: (whatever: Whatever) => T | Whatever = val => val ): (T | Whatever)[] {
  return values.map(value => getter(value));
}
```

**Update to address clarified question**:

> I wanted to avoid to return "Whatever | T" because everytime I will
>   call this function I will have to check the response type (Whatever or
>   T).

When you call this function, only two overloaded signatures are taken into account, TypeScript does not use implementation signature when doing overload resolution at call sites of  `doSomething()`. In fact, implementation return type could simply be declared as `any`, as it's done in the overload [documentation examples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) - it's used for type-checking the implementation only, and the implementation is often obvious enough so stricter types do not provide much benefit there.

> I would like to write code to take the return type on the getter function and use as T.

If you omit generic argument when calling `doSomething`, the compiler will infer `T` from the `getter` return type. I think the following example does what you want:

```
interface Whatever { w: string };

function doSomething<T>(values: Whatever[], getter: (whatever: Whatever) => T): T[];
function doSomething(values: Whatever[]): Whatever[];
function doSomething<T>(values: Whatever[], getter: (whatever: Whatever) => T | Whatever = val => val ): (T | Whatever)[] {
  return values.map(value => getter(value));
}

function example() {
    const getter1 = (whatever: Whatever) => whatever.w; // returns string
    const getter2 = (whatever: Whatever) => whatever.w.length; // returns number

    const values: Whatever[] = [];

    const r0 = doSomething(values); // const r1: Whatever[]
    const r1 = doSomething(values, getter1); // const r1: string[]
    const r2 = doSomething(values, getter2); // const r2: number[]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wanted to avoid to return "Whatever | T" because everytime I will call this function I will have to check the response type (Whatever or T). Let's take an example:
If i call this method with a custom getter, typescript will not knows that the response type and then you can access Whatever properties and also T property.
Any idea to keep this function strongly typed ?

Comment: I would like to write code to take the return type on the getter function and use as T. Is there any way for that ? That way if I use Whatever as returned type it would be obvious to use it for T.

Comment: Overloads was exaclty what I was looking for ! I was not aware of the existence of a such feature. Approved your answer ! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

As you want a default behavior when no getter is given I think it would be completly ok to have a default getter that simply tries to cast: `val => val as T`

```
function doSomething <T>(values: Whatever[], getter: (whatever: Whatever) => T = val => val as T): T[] {
    return values.map(getter);
}
```

And with Typescript being only syntax sugar for typesafety during 'compile-time', this means: 'Try to get the value as it is without any mapping whatsoever'. So if you think this through, if no getter is given, this means it will not actually change the values of the array. Depending the use case you might as well do

```
function doSomething <T>(values: Whatever[], getter?: (whatever: Whatever) => T): T[] {
    if (getter === undefined) { return values as T[]; }

    return values.map(value => getter(value));
}
```

and skip the map() that will do nothing but copy the array, and if that is what you want in that  case:
`return [...values] as T[]` instead to return a copy.